# Window vs Var to declare variable

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between using var and not using var in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/difference-between-using-var-and-not-using-var-in-javascript)
>   [Should I use window.variable or var?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904166/should-i-use-window-variable-or-var)

I have seen two ways to declare a class in javascript.

like

```
window.ABC = ....
```

or

```
var ABC = ....
```

Is there any difference in terms of using the class/ variable?

Comment: There are no classes in JavaScript. You are just declaring a  variable. Please provide some more information.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`window.ABC` scopes the ABC variable to window scope (effectively global.)

`var ABC` scopes the ABC variable to whatever function the ABC variable resides in.

Comment: if I declare window.var outside all the functions i.e. in the script but not in any function, then that will also create a global variable. So, is in this case is there any difference between window.var and var??

Answer (score 10):

`var` creates a variable for the current scope. So if you do it in a function, it won't be accessible outside of it.

```
function foo() {
    var a = "bar";
    window.b = "bar";
}

foo();
alert(typeof a); //undefined
alert(typeof b); //string
alert(this == window); //true
```

Answer (score 4):

```
window.ABC = "abc"; //Visible outside the function
var ABC = "abc"; // Not visible outside the function.
```

If you are outside of a function declaring variables, they are equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

`window` makes the variable global to the window. Unless you have a reason for doing otherwise, declare variables with `var`.

Answer (score 2):

The major difference is that your data is now attached to the window object instead of just existing in memory. Otherwise, it is the same.