# How to init() a JS inside Laravel Blade file

Tags: javascript, laravel

Normally I use a javascript file to import different JS files. Now having a difficulty to do it so. The project I am working on went wild and have a 5Mb JS file and I only want a piece of it to load on one page. 
In a Javascript file I could import the Module like this,

```
import {Module} from "./components/Module";
```

and use as
`Module.init();`

But what I am trying to do is load this Module in a blade file. The js file lives under `resources/assets/js/components/Module.js`

Because this folder is not public I am not sure if I use something like

`<script src="../../../resources/assets/js/components/Module.js"></script>` on the page. Well, tried it but did not work as well.
All I want to be able to init the JS like `Module.init();` inside my blade file.

I would really appreciate and directions as I am a bit confused right now:(

Answer (score 1):

You cant import your files from `resources` directory, the only visible part of your application to users should be `public` folder so you should put your file into the `public` folder. for example
`public/js/modjule.js`
and import it like this

`<script src="{{ asset('js/module.js') }}"`

if your site is on a `https` protocol you can use `secure_asset()`

`<script src="{{ secure_asset('js/module.js') }}"`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @AH.Pooladvand,  the methods of Module is inside the `index.js` which is under public. This `index.js` is also included on the page but I cannot do anything like `Module.init()` which runs some scripts and AJAX codes. Looks like I'll need to find a different way :) thanks for making it clear.

Comment: @JerryLi I'm not really a js expert but I think to be able to do a thing like `Module.init()` you should make your `Module` as a window variable like jquery's `$` variable for more info read this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082886/window-vs-var-to-declare-variable