# how can i pass a variable content into a function as parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(function () {

    var info = JSON.parse($('#userInfo').text());
    var empFirstName = info.EmployeedFirstName;
    var empLastName = info.EmployeedLastName;
    var empFullName = empFirstName + " " + empLastName;
});
```

I am calling the summary function from a hyper link. I only want to call the summary function when the link is clicked on.

```
<a onclick="summary();">Summary</a>

function summary(empFullName){
}
```

Comment: Scope of `empFullName` isn't available outside of  `$(function(){})` since you declared it with `var` inside it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you, but you should look into the `window` object, global variables, and why they may be considered bad.

```
$(function () {    
    var info = JSON.parse($('#userInfo').text());
    var empFirstName = info.EmployeedFirstName;
    var empLastName = info.EmployeedLastName;
    window.empFullName = empFirstName + " " + empLastName;
});

function summary(empFullName){
    // use empFullName here
}
```

Then modify your link to pass in the global

```
<a onclick="summary(empFullName);">Summary</a>
```

Some related reading: [Should I use window.variable or var?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904166/should-i-use-window-variable-or-var)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the inline function call from the link and add a click event handler to your link, then call the function and pass your variable to it, when the click handler gets called. Take a look at the snippet and you will get the idea.

```js
$(function () {

  //var info = JSON.parse($('#userInfo').text());
  //var empFirstName = info.EmployeedFirstName;
  //var empLastName = info.EmployeedLastName;
  var empFullName = 'foo' + " " + 'bar';
  
  // added click event handler here
  $('a').on('click', function() {
     summary(empFullName); // call summary with empFullName
  });
  
});

function summary(empFullName){
  console.log(empFullName);
  $('#output').text(empFullName);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">Summary</a>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: am calling the summary function from a hyper link. I only want to call the summary function when the link is clicked on.                        <a onclick="summary();">Summary</a>

Comment: @user3479738 you should add that to the question

Comment: @user3479738 You did not say that in your question.